# Websphere Liberty: Context root not found

Tags: jsp, websphere, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to start and application on IBM Websphere Liberty (Version 17.0.0.1).

server.xml:

```
...
<featureManager>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
...
<application id=<id> location=<location> name=<name> type="ear">
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,third-party" delegation="parentLast" />
</application>
...
```

Last lines from the console log:

```
[INFO    ] CNTR4001I: The <ejbModule>.jar EJB module in the <ear> application has started successfully.
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: <webModule>.jar
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module <webModule> has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://<hostname>:9080/<contextRoot>/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application <ear> started in 14.240 seconds.
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost startWebApp" at ffdc_18.03.28_16.26.36.0.log
[INFO    ] SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at <Liberty installation dir>\usr\servers\<serverName>\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
```

FFDC:

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [3/28/18 16:26:36:634 EEST]
Exception = java.lang.NullPointerException
Source = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost
probeid = startWebApp
Stack Dump = java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:568)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:267)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:354)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:324)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.getInjectionClasses(WebApp.java:324)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.getComponentNameSpaceConfiguration(WebApp.java:288)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.processImpl(ReferenceContextImpl.java:347)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.osgi.internal.OSGiReferenceContextImpl.process(OSGiReferenceContextImpl.java:31)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationStart(WebApp.java:254)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6565)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:468)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:1051)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.access$000(WebContainer.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer$2.run(WebContainer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:483)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
```

The FFDC log isn't very insightful on the cause from my perspective but using -verbose:class I can see that the last classes loaded before the exception is generated are jsp related. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It is hard to tell base on this stack.  Can you share a sample of the app so I can try and debug locally? Thanks!

Comment: or set trace
<logging traceSpecification="*=info=enabled:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.ws.jsp*=all" maxFileSize="40" maxFiles="20" traceFormat="BASIC"/>

Comment: Remove that whole `<classloader ...>` line

Comment: what application are you trying to deploy ? might help to apply trace on the application packages also